# Undefined symbol: `stdout` with picolibc - despite the symbol being defined in my startup code (only with LTO)

Tags: linker, embedded, clang, bazel, bazel-cpp

I'm trying to convert an embedded project from CMake (via a brief detour to meson) to Bazel. We are using the [llvm-embedded](https://github.com/ARM-software/LLVM-embedded-toolchain-for-Arm) toolchain which uses [picolibc](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc). I manually setup the toolchain more or less based on [bazel-embedded](https://github.com/bazelembedded/bazel-embedded) (which doesn't support llvm-embedded directly).

So far, everything seems to work, except that the link fails with `undefined symbol: stdout`, which gets referenced from `tinystdio/puts.c`, part of `picolibc`. Indeed, ["Picolibc and Operating Systems"](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc/blob/main/doc/os.md) explains that we have to provide that symbol. We do that as part of our startup C-file, basically exactly copying that documentation.

With both CMake and meson, that links perfectly, but I can't get it to link with bazel. Some of the differences I did notice are that bazel uses the C driver (`clang`) instead of the C++ driver (`clang++`), see [bazel issue 11122](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11122). The assumption is that the difference is mostly unimportant, the C++ linking issues can be resolved by either linking directly to `libc++` and `libc++abi`, or by passing `--driver-mode=g++`.

Also, it does link correctly without `-flto=thin`.
While for this `blinky` test we don't really need LTO, we do rely on LTO in our larger builds, and we need it to get working.

Here is the full linker command line created by bazel in one of the failed attempts:

```
/path/to/LLVMEmbeddedToolchainForArm-17.0.1-Darwin-AArch64/bin/clang
  -o bazel-out/.../blinky
  bazel-out/.../blinky.o
  ...some-dependency-libs.a...
  bazel-out/.../libapollo4-fam-picolibc-startup.a
  -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib
  -T mcus/apollo4l/llvm-picolibc.ld
  -Wl,--start-group
    -lc -lc++ -lc++abi -lunwind -lclang_rt.builtins -lm -lcrt0
    bazel-out/.../libapollo4-fam-picolibc-startup.a
  -Wl,--end-group
  -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined
  -Wl,-v -v -Wl,-S -Wl,--gc-sections
  '-march=armv7em' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' -mlittle-endian
  -Os '-flto=thin' '-fuse-ld=lld' '--driver-mode=g++'
  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
  '-mabi=aapcs' -mthumb '--target=armv7em-none-eabi'
  -static
```

The `stdout` symbol is provided in `libapollo4-fam-picolibc-startup.a`. The `-nodefaultlibs -nostdlib`, and then packing all stdlibs between `-Wl,--start-group`, `-Wl,--end-group` is my heaviest gun I have been able to muster, to no effect.

For comparison, here is the successful meson command line:

```
/path/to/LLVMEmbeddedToolchainForArm-17.0.1-Darwin-AArch64/bin/clang++
  -o blinky
  blinky.afx.p/blinky.cpp.o
  -flto=thin -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined
  -fuse-ld=/path/zo/LLVMEmbeddedToolchainForArm-17.0.1-Darwin-AArch64/bin/ld.lld
  -ffunction-sections
  -fdata-sections
  -fomit-frame-pointer
  --target=armv7em-none-eabi
  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
  -Wl,--start-group
    libstartup.a
    ...dependency-libs.a...
    -T/path/to/llvm-picolibc.ld
    -Wl,-Map,/path/to/blinky.map
    /path/to/LLVMEmbeddedToolchainForArm-17.0.1-Darwin-AArch64//lib/clang-runtimes/arm-none-eabi/armv7m_soft_fpv4_sp_d16/lib/libcrt0.a
  -Wl,--end-group
```

Here, the `stdout` is found in `libstartup.a`.

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: You are telling us that `stdout` is defined in your start-up code, but you have not _shown_ that.  You mentioned C++ compilation, is `stdout` defined in a C++ module?  If so then you need `extern "C"` to prevent the symbol being name mangled.  It needs to be a C symbol not a C++ symbol which will be augmented with type and scope information in C++.

Comment: LTO is good at removing stuff it thinks are not required.  Even if you use compiler directives to prevent that I have found.

Comment: @Clifford: Yeah, I did not show that. The startup code is basically the only `.c` file I have in the project, which puts the compiler in C mode for that file. Also, the output of `llvm-nm` on `libapollo4-fam-picolibc-startup.a` lists a `-------- D stdout` global writable data symbol by the name of `stdout`, which indicates no C++ name mangling occurs.

Comment: Interestingly, without LTO, the output of `llvm-nm` is `00000000 R stdout`, so a global read-only data symbol.

Comment: In the past (with less intelligent linkers) I have encountered cases where you have to mention a library more than once to resolve a symbol, because it is referenced by something in another library that itself must be pulled in. Perhaps the problem is that you need to include the library that has stdout symbol either in a different place on the link line, or even twice (e.g. before and then after -lc)?